# How to match "escape" non-printable character in a regex?

Tags: java, regex, ansi-escape

I've found a howto, http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/214-how-to-match-nonprintable-characters-with-a-regular-expression/ , but non of the codes, \e, \x1b, \x1B,  work for me in Java.

**EDIT**

I am trying to replace the ANSI escape sequences (specifically, color sequences) of a Linux terminal command's output.
In Python the replace pattern would look like "\x1b[34;01m", which means blue bold text. This same pattern does not work in Java. I tried to replace "[34;01m" separately, and it worked, so the problem is \x1b.
And I *am* doing the "[" escaping using Pattern.quote().

**EDIT**

```
Map<String,String> escapeMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
escapeMap.put("\\x1b[01;34m", "</span><span style=\"color:blue;font-weight:bold\">");
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File("/home/ch00k/gun.output"));
FileChannel fc = stream.getChannel();
MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
String message = Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString();
stream.close();
String patternString = Pattern.quote(StringUtils.join(escapeMap.keySet(), "|"));
System.out.println(patternString);
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(message);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while(matcher.find()) {
    matcher.appendReplacement(sb, escapeMap.get(matcher.group()));
    }
matcher.appendTail(sb);
String formattedMessage = sb.toString();
System.out.println(formattedMessage);
```

***EDIT***
Here is the code I've ended up with:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.*;

class CreateMessage {
    public static void message() throws IOException {
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File("./gun.output"));
        FileChannel fc = stream.getChannel();
        MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
        String message = Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString();
        stream.close();
        Map<String,String> tokens = new HashMap<String,String>();
        tokens.put("root", "nobody");
        tokens.put(Pattern.quote("[01;34m"), "qwe");
        String patternString = "(" + StringUtils.join(tokens.keySet(), "|") + ")";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(message);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(tokens.get(matcher.group()));
            matcher.appendReplacement(sb, tokens.get(matcher.group()));
        }
        matcher.appendTail(sb);

        System.out.println(sb.toString());

    }
}
```

The file gun.output contains the output of `ls -la --color=always /`
Now, the problem is that I'm getting a NullPointerException if I'm trying to match `Pattern.quote("[01;34m")`. Everything matches fine except of the strings, that contain `[`, even though I quote them. The exception is the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:699)
    at org.minuteware.jgun.CreateMessage.message(CreateMessage.java:32)
    at org.minuteware.jgun.Main.main(Main.java:23)
```

***EDIT***

So, according to http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/releases/1.4regex/, the escape character should be matched with `"\u001B"`, which indeed works in my case. The problem is, if I use `tokens.put("\u001B" + Pattern.quote("[01;34m"), "qwe");`, I still get the above mentioned NPE.

Comment: Could you show your regex and an example of what specifically you are trying to match or exclude?

Comment: If you don't show the code, no one will spot mistakes you haven't thought of.  For instance: are you quote()ing the whole string, or just the "["?  If the whole string, that's the problem.  This is my third guess at what you're doing - showing us would get you a useful answer a lot quicker and waste a lot less of our time.

Comment: @Becuzz Sorry. I added my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper value for "escape" character in a regexp is `\u001B`

Answer (score 1):

`quote()` is to make a pattern that will match the input string *verbatim*.  Your string has pattern language in it.  Look at the output from quote() - you'll see that it's trying to literally find the four characters \x1b.

Comment: My pattern string looks like this: "\\x1B[01;34m", but it does not work. I also tried "\\e[1;34m", which does not work either.

Comment: @Chook - The bracket needs to be escaped (\\\).

Comment: I tried it another way:   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\x1b" + Pattern.quote("[01;34m"));   But it gives me an NPE.

Comment: @Andriy - I copied and pasted this and got no NPE when I executed it.

Answer (score 0):

The ansi escape sequences are of the following form **[\033[34;01m]**

where \033 is ANSI character 033 (oct) or 1b in Hex or 27 in decimal. You need to use the following regexp:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\033\\[34;01m");
```

You can use an octal (\033) or hex (\x1b) representation when you're using a non-printable character in a java string.

Comment: \x works fine.  See [the docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: Also, escape sequences don't begin with a bracket.  They begin with an escape.

Comment: Um... the pattern still begins with a bracket.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I've been working on stripping ANSI color codes from colorized log4j files and this little pattern seems to do the trick for all of the cases I've come across:

```
Pattern.compile("(\\u001B\\[\\d+;\\d+m)+")
```